# How to set HTML lang attribute dynamically on NextJs Document?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a multi language site and need to set up the HTML lang attribute according the language for the each page.

I try to pass the value in context, but does not update when page changes.

Here the current code:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import GlobalContext , {eLanguage }from '../components/GlobalContext' //my global context 

export default class MyDocument extends Document {

static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  return { ...initialProps }
}
static contextType = GlobalContext;
render() {

  console.debug('Started')
  console.debug('language:'+ this.context.language) 

  return (
    <Html lang={eLanguage[this.context.language]}> //if the first page loaded as lang 'en' it sets 'en' and apply to all other pages.
      <Head>
      </Head>
      <body>       
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

}

Update: 
The language of each page can be inferred from the page route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using document object the lang attribute can be set like this:

```
var language= ...
switch (language) {
    case en:  document.documentElement.lang = 'en-us'; break;
    ...
}
```

This lang attribute will not be set on the initial html, before page is hydrated, but will still pass chrome "hreflang" audit check.

Answer (score 32):

I believe the best solution here is to use a custom `./pages/_document.js` file and override the document itself.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

More explanation can be found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: How do i go about making this work with Typescript? Importing Typescript seems to have broken it :/

Comment: This doesn't set the `lang` dynamically - `"en"` is hard coded. You need a way to pass in the language.

Answer (score 24):

If you use [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) you can set the language to the html tag. Anything that you pass to the Head component will be either placed in the `<head>` or `<html>`.

Next Head works similar to React Helmet, so for your case you could do something along these lines:

- Create a component and import Head from "next/head"
- Inside the Head tag you add the `<html lang={lan} />` to the component.

Then you can pass the desired language to that component, then import the component on the desired pages.

```js
import React from "react"
import Head from "next/head"

const Language = ({title, lang}) => (
  <Head>
    <html lang={lang} />
    <title>{title}</title>
  </Head>
)

export default Language
```

That html bit will be injected inside the `<html>` tag.

Note that even if we inject it like this the console will log the following error: `TypeError: n is null`.

Comment: I got this error on the console:head-manager.js?0ea4:2 Warning: next-head-count is missing. https://err.sh/next.js/next-head-count-missing. 
In either case, that hist is not a way to go.

Comment: Also note that Html tag is parent of Head tag. i don't thing Head component it means to be used in this way.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer. Same as provided in the nextjs docs.

Comment: @GabrielLinassi, this is not quite the same as in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), where it says you should do this in _document. Doing it elsewhere technically works, though perhaps you can't rely on it to keep working, and it gives the console waning `Warning: next-head-count is missing` as mentioned above.

Comment: @ArneHugo That's right. Thanks for the correction. I checked here on my code and it's defined on the _document as well.

Comment: @MiguelSlv <Head> component in _document.js is different than <Head> component that we use to update <head> content. <Head> inside _document.js is being imported from 'next/document' and <Head> inside pages are being loaded from 'next/head'

Comment: This solution (and _document.js also) works only on full page refresh

Answer (score 17):

Next 10 supports [Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) and will add `lang` dynamically leaving you with:

```
<Html>
  <Head />
  <body>       
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
  </body>
</Html>
```

Comment: For future readers, this is not currently supported if you're using SSG via `next export` - [Reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9160#issuecomment-752713231) and [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#how-does-this-work-with-static-generation)

Answer (score 8):

Create `_document.js` in `pages`` folder
and use this:

```
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(context);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang={this.props.locale}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

for localization use `next.config.js`

```
{
 i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'de',],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

Comment: If you're using Next.js own i18n then you don't need to set the `lang` yourself. You use the router and Next.js adds / updates the `lang` attribute itself.

Comment: I think this might be the correct way to do this, as it doesn't generate any errors. [The NextJS guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-document) seems to imply that's how they want it done.

Answer (score 6):

I implemented this by adding this to next.config.js file:

```
i18n: {
// These are all the locales you want to support in
// your application
locales: ['en-US'],
// This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
// a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
defaultLocale: 'en-US' }
```

I didn't have the need to create a custom _document.js

Comment: careful, that **ALONE**  would get you 404 on every single page.

Comment: you may need to set `localeDetection` to false to avoid unwanted redirections, when used with more than one `locales`

Answer (score 4):

Nextjs versions after 10 provides default localization support,
You don't have to configure much.

It automatically adds lang attribute to html, but still there is **no support until now** with v12 **for dir attribute** to include that we can use this small trick inside **_document file**.

```
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

function Document(props: any) {

  return (
    <Html dir={props.__NEXT_DATA__.locale === "en" ? "ltr" : "rtl"}>
      <Head></Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}

export default Document;
```

**The end result would be**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `lang` attribute without creating `_document.js`

All you need to do is add this code to your `next.config.js`:

```js
i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a React useEffect hook to set the document's language without having to change the way that Next.js generates the HTML tag itself.

Within your page component or another appropriate component, include the useEffect hook:

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
```

And then add the hook:

```
const MyPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.lang = "en-us";
  });
  // The rest of your component
}
```

This passes Lighthouse's check for "hreflang", and if your site has multiple languages, you can use this to set the page language per page.

Comment: this is not SEO friendly unfortunately

Comment: @itsjavi doesn't matter - for a web application this works. As far as I can tell, if you're not using the Next.js i18n this is the only way to _dynamically_ set the `lang` attribute without requiring a full page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers assume that the lang attribute is on the html tag is an alternative to link with a hreflang attribute. However, this is not the case!

You should provide both, as they are complementary.

This is how I implemented my hreflang links in NEXT.JS:

```
export const LayoutController = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
         {router.locales.map((locale) => (
          <link
            key={locale}
            rel="alternate"
            href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}${
              locale === DEFAULT_LOCALE ? '' : `/${locale}`
            }${router.asPath}`}
            hrefLang={locale}
          />
        ))}
      </Head>
      {children}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

These links were generated in my html page:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To overide default nextjs settings create the file ./pages/_document.js and extend the Document class as shown below:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Custom attributes are allowed as props, like lang:

```
<Html lang="en">
```

You can read more about custom document here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document